# How to write a query for getting free seats in a hostel

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, select

I created a database for a hostel, I've built all tables in SQL Server, now I'm trying to write sine queries. I want to get room numbers with available free seats in them.

I have tables `Students`, `Contracts`, `Rooms`.

`Contracts` has a column `Student` which references the `StudentId` in `Students` and `Contracts` has the column `Room` which references the `RoomId` of the `Rooms` table. `RoomId` is a room number.

`Room` also has a column `NumberSeats` which is a total number of seats in the room. So I think that's enough for understanding my problem and writing a query.

I want to get room numbers with available free seats in them. I don't know how to implement this, I'm new in SQL, so all I try goes to nothing. Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you edit your question with your query(es) even though they are not working correctly?

Comment: @Lesya I could make a query for getting a number of people living in a certain room `SELECT Count(*) FROM Students WHERE StudentId IN (SELECT Student FROM Contracts WHERE Room=711)` and that's all. I tried to get around with that but I can't get how to make it for every room, not for certain

Comment: It'll be better if you'll post your schema and your queries on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Using Group by is the solution as given by @Lesya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all the Students mentioned by their ID in your Contracts table, you can extract data by referring just Contracts and Rooms. You can try by joining two tables, counting the number of students per room and adding a condition into the having clause:

```
SELECT b.RoomId,
  b.NumberSeats,
  COUNT(a.Student)
FROM Rooms b
LEFT JOIN Contracts a
ON a.Room=b.RoomId
GROUP BY b.RoomId,
  b.NumberSeats
HAVING b.NumberSeats>COUNT(a.Student);
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot and works fine! Need to dig deeper into aggregate functions

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared this example for you.
ddl + query -->

```
create table student
(id number,
name varchar2(100));

create table room
(id  number,
name varchar2(100));

create table contract
(student_id number,
room_id number);

create table number_seats
(room_id number,
number_seats number);

insert into student values(1, 'Jon');
insert into student values(2, 'George');
insert into student values(3, 'Ian');
insert into student values(4, 'Alex');
insert into student values(5, 'Mary');

insert into room values(1, 'room1');
insert into room values(2, 'room2');
insert into room values(3, 'room3');
insert into room values(4, 'room4');
insert into room values(5, 'room5');

insert into number_seats values(1, 1);
insert into number_seats values(2, 2);
insert into number_seats values(3, 3);
insert into number_seats values(4, 2);
insert into number_seats values(5, 1);

insert into contract values(1, 1);
insert into contract values(2, 2);
insert into contract values(3, 3);
insert into contract values(4, 4);
insert into contract values(5, 4);

select * from room;
select * from student;
select * from contract;
select * from number_seats;


select cont.room_id, num_seats.number_seats - count(*)
from student st 
join contract cont on st.id=cont.student_id
join room ro on ro.id=cont.room_id
join number_seats num_seats on num_seats.room_id=ro.id
group by cont.room_id, num_seats.number_seats 
union
select ro.id, num_seats.number_seats
from room ro left join contract co on ro.id=co.room_id
join number_seats num_seats on num_seats.room_id=ro.id
where co.room_id is null
order by 1;
```

Result is

```
|roomNumber|freeSeats|
|    1     |  0      |
|    2     |  1      |
|    3     |  2      |
|    4     |  0      |
|    5     |  1      |
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got that I need to use aggregate functions, thank you